# how to scroll tk canvas smoothly by mouse wheel

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to scroll canvas, so I use this code to bind to mouse wheel:

```
def _on_mousewheel(event):         
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")  

canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
```

but every time I use the mouse wheel, the canvas scrolls like jumping one position to another.
So I try change yscrollincrement to 10:

```
canvas.config(yscrollincrement = 10)
```

It is more smooth, but not enough for me, and if I change it to 1, it is too slow to scroll.

I try to use a loop to do it and use time.sleep to slow down the speed, but it did not work, it will freeze until loop end and scroll to the end position without process.

How do I scroll canvas smoothly like Chrome or Firefox?

All I want is scroll like yscrollincrement = 1, but fast.

try to use after:

```
def _on_mousewheel(event): 
    canv.config(yscrollincrement = 1) 
    num = 0
    def sc(num, ud):
        canv.yview_scroll(ud, "units") 
        num += 1
        if num < 500:
        #root or canv is the same
            canv.after(1,sc(num, ud))
    ud = int(-1*(event.delta/120))
    sc(num, ud)
    canv.config(yscrollincrement = 0)
```

Comment: You should not use `time.sleep()`, instead use `root.after()`, if root is what you bind Tk() to. Try and see if that works

Comment: @SneakyTurtle Not useful, still freeze and jump. code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want is scroll like yscrollincrement = 1, but fast.

You can increase the value of "units" for faster scrolling.

```
canvas.yview_scroll(speed, 'units')
```

Sample:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Label


def FrameWidth(event, canvas):
   canvas_width = event.width
   canvas.itemconfig("my_tag", width = canvas_width)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
   canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def retag(tag, *args):
   for widget in args:
      widget.bindtags((tag,) + widget.bindtags())

def _on_mousewheel(event, canvas):
   if event.num == 5:
      speed = 10     # between 8 and 13 gives good speed and smoothness
   else:
      speed = -10    # between 8 and 13 gives good speed and smoothness
   canvas.yview_scroll(speed, 'units')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x400+300+100')
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white', yscrollincrement=1)      # 1 makes it more smooth
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame = Frame(root, bg='white')
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw', tags="my_tag")
l1 = Label(frame, text='Label 1', bg='black', fg='white', height=3)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=2)
l2 = Label(frame, text='Label 2', bg='black', fg='white', height=3)
l2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=2)
l3 = Label(frame, text='Label 2', bg='black', fg='white', height=3)
l3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=2)
l4 = Label(frame, text='Label 2', bg='black', fg='white', height=3)
l4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=2)
retag("special", canvas, frame, l1, l2, l3, l4)

canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: FrameWidth(event, canvas))
root.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
canvas.bind_class('special', '<Button-4>', lambda event: _on_mousewheel(event, canvas))      # Button 4 and 5 for mouse scroll on linux. Not sure of windows.
canvas.bind_class('special', '<Button-5>', lambda event: _on_mousewheel(event, canvas))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has been a long time, but nothing is too late, I have a solution:

```py
def on_mouse_wheel(event=None):
    def _scroll(e=None):
        nonlocal shift_scroll, scroll, scrolled
        if scrolled == 105:
            return
        if shift_scroll:
            canvas.xview_scroll(scroll, 'units')
        else:
            canvas.yview_scroll(scroll, 'units')
        scrolled += 1
        self.after(5, _scroll)

    scrolled = 0
    shift_scroll = (event.state & 0x1) != 0
    scroll = -1 if event.delta > 0 else 1
    _scroll()
```

Here you can bind your mouse-wheel event to the function and it will scroll smoothly.
If you want to increase or decrease the time you can change it in the 11th line in `self.after()`.
**NOTE: The time in `self.after()` is in milliseconds.**